# Can't create simple socket with Ruby - Errno::ECONNREFUSED

Tags: ruby, macos, sockets, network-programming

I can't create even simplest socket in Ruby, when I try to execute

```
s = TCPSocket.open('localhost', 2000)
```

in PRY, its always throws an error:

```
Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused - connect(2) for "127.0.0.1" port 2000
```

Could it be some permission issue? I have no idea even where to start with it...
I am newbie weekend programmer, so please be forgiving:)
I am working on OS X El Captain.

Answer (score 1):

Connection refused since there is no server listening on tcp://127.0.0.1:2000.

If you want to run a server, use `TCPServer`:

```
TCPServer.new('localhost', 2000)
```

If you want to connect to a server, run it first.